# Blob Image information back into <input> tag?

Tags: php, input, blob

I succeeded in storing all the image information as a blob in MySQL via the form tag and php.
Now I'm trying to make an update form using PHP5. However, I'm not sure how to take all the information back from MySQL and show it to users that an image has been already posted.. like any other typical forum / blog pages that shows previously added files.

Any suggestions..? Thank you.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="UpdateNewsPHP.php">
Title  : <input name='TitleFieldToAdd' type='text' size='20' value='<?php echo $row["Title"] ?>'/> <br/>
Thread : <textarea name='ThreadFieldToAdd' cols="40" rows="10"><?php echo $row["Thread"] ?></textarea> <br/>
<!-- Here I have no clue how to deal with them... :( -->
Image  :  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input type="file" id='ImageFieldToAdd' name="files[]" /> <br/>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload me!">
```

and this is the information I store in MySQL

```
$title = $_REQUEST['TitleFieldToAdd'];
$thread = $_REQUEST['ThreadFieldToAdd'];
$file_content = file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]);
$file_content = mysql_real_escape_string($file_content);
$file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
$file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][0];
$file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][0];
$datePosted = date("Y-m-d");*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to leave your file upload stuff asis. If a file has already been uploaded, you display it another section of the form. Imgs can be embedded with an `<img>` tag (pointing at another script which retrieves/serves up the raw image data from the database). Non-displayable fields (pdf, zip, etc..) you can just put in a direct download link.

Then your form will look something like

```
[input1]
[input2]
You previously uploaded: [link/image to uploaded data]
[input file] - would you like to replace this data?
```

As such, your form building script would not actually retrieve the uploaded file data. Just its metadata (type/size).

Comment: Whoa.. never thought about that! Yeah, I could simply show some info and let them update it if they want... Thank you!